# Different Return Type with Same Method Signature (Focus on Usability)

Tags: c#

I've searched for the answer and parsed through a lot of posts, but I'm not quite sure I have a full understanding or a solution to my issue.

I'm writing a framework for used with CodedUI and my company's application.  There are scenarios where adding data to a specific field in our application can return one of several message boxes.  I'm trying to figure out the best solution to make writing the test cases as simple as possible.  The testers who will be writing the test cases may not have a strong understanding of C#, so I've attempted to make using the framework simple.  I also want to avoid making the tester resort to casting in the test case.

I've thought of several solutions, but nothing feels right to me from an end-user perspective.

First, I can just have a void return type and let the tester create an instance of the message box expected.  The problem here is that I'm leaving the instantiation up to the tester.  This might be okay and the eventual solution, but I'm trying to offload that and let the framework worry about the implementation details.

```
public class Framework
{
    public void AddData(string data)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void TestCase()
    {
        var framework = new Framework();
        framework.AddData("some data");
        var message = new Message1();
    }
}
```

My second choice is the use of generics.  I can just have a base class for all message boxes and let the tester add in what they want.  This seems reasonable and a better solution then the first, but I have two concerns here.  First, there are occasions (though not frequent) where the instantiation of a Message requires specific constructor data so the implementation on the framework side for AddData() may require multiple methods (ie. AddData1(), AddData2()...).  Second, I have some worry about adding in generics for the end-user.

```
public class Framework
{
    public T AddData<T>(string data) where T : MessageBox, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void TestCase()
    {
        var framework = new Framework();
        var message = framework.AddData<Message1>("some data");
    }
}
```

Lastly, of course, I can have multiple methods with specific return types.  I hate this solution as it feels ugly.

```
public class Framework
{
    public Message1 AddData1(string data)
    {
        return new Message1();
    }

    public Message2 AddData2(string data)
    {
        return new Message2();
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void TestCase()
    {
        var framework = new Framework();
        var message1 = framework.AddData1("some data");
        var message2 = framework.AddData2("some data");
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd love to have one method with multiple return types.  I know it's not natively supported, but I'm not sure on how to implement a work-around (if that's possible).  Something like this:

```
public class Framework
{
    public Message1 AddData(string data)
    {
        return new Message1();
    }

    public Message2 AddData(string data)
    {
        return new Message2();
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void TestCase()
    {
        var framework = new Framework();
        var message1 = framework.AddData("some data");
        var message2 = framework.AddData("some data");
    }
}
```

And of course, I'm open to any alternatives I haven't thought of.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's imagine that was possible. Why would the first invocation of `framework.AddData("some data");` return a `Message1` and the second a `Message2`? What would the third invocation return?

Comment: If you want multiple return types, use generics or casting with a factory pattern

Comment: Different errant data could cause different messages.  For example, a date in the past could return one message, a date on a weekend can return another, etc.

Comment: Sure, but that implies you are calling a single method that has that logic inside it. How would the _compiler_ or _runtime_ know which of the two methods to call?

Comment: I agree that it wouldn't know...or couldn't know.  Which is why I'm not sure there is a way to implement what I really want.  But I'm only 1 year into c# development and am hoping I'm missing something or there is a better solution I haven' thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the Generics option.

Your first concern can be solved by adding a `Func<T>` parameter as a factory method:

```
public class Framework
{
    public T AddData<T>(string data, Func<T> factory) where T : MessageBox 
    {
        T returnValue = factory();
        returnValue.data = data;
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var normalMessageBox = framework.AddData("data", () => new NormalMessageBox());

var specialMessageBox = framework.AddData("data", () => new SpecialMessageBox(1, "title"));
```

However, this might make your second concern even bigger - since you say it's intended to be used by people with not so strong c# skills.
That can be solved with good documentation and code samples.

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/ZQDXE98922)